# saving to a dataset using datagridview issues

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

Ok, I have a datagrid view and i bind this to a dataset.  I have a dataset called `searchEmployeeDS` that gets specific employee information from the DB.  it then binds to the datagridview.

after that data gets bound. i change a few columns programatically in the datagridview. for example `dgvEmployees.Item(2, x).Value = EmployeeName`. Now the issue is , if i just click save it doesn't detect if there has been any changes. this is my code.

```
   If searchEmployeesDS.HasChanges Then
   Dim updateDataSet As DataSet = PhoneService.updateChanges(searchEmployeesDS.GetChanges())
   searchEmployeesDS.Merge(updateDataSet)
   searchEmployeesDS.AcceptChanges()
   MsgBox("Save Complete")
```

But of course if i modify the grid using user interaction it will and then save will work.  But sometimes there is not user modification. i just display the data and update a few columns programmatically but it doesn't pick up the change. how can i force it to save.

```
            searchEmployeesDS = PhoneService.searchEmployees(PhoneNum)
            dgvEmployees.DataSource = Nothing
            dgvEmployees.Columns.Clear()

            searchBS = Nothing
            searchBS = New BindingSource()
            searchBS.DataSource = searchEmployeesDS.Tables(0)
            PhoneEmpNavigator.BindingSource = searchBS
            dgvEmployees.DataSource = searchBS
```

Comment: Do you have a `BindingNavigator` object associated with your binding source?

Comment: Yes i do.. the code for that is. added above

Comment: When do you want the db to reflect the changes of the `datagridview`?

Comment: Right after it loads the data into the DGV, I update columns programaticly.  so right after that i want the user to look at the row review it and be able to click save.  They may or maynot have to make any changes to the grid.  but the thing is again it doesn't detect that there was a change if all i do is programaticly make a change right after the grid is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This code has worked for me in the past. Under your `OnClick` event for the save, I would suggest:

```
Me.Validate()

Me.dgvEmployees.EndEdit()

Me.searchBS.EndEdit()

Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.searchEmployeesDS)
```

Let me know if this works for you. If not, I can try editing further.

Comment: looks like i had to add the endedit for searchbs to get it to work thanks

Comment: Glad to help, please mark this as the answer if you think it worked well enough?